# Httpclient execute always fails after second time (IOExpception, socket timeout)

Tags: android, sockets

Anyone sees the reason? There doesn't seem to be any problems with the server, as I can send curl requests all the time. I get socket timeout exception only after the second time I try to query the server. If I restart the application it starts working for first time and then stops.

```
 String params = String.format(params);
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    int connectionTimeout = 1000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, connectionTimeout);
    int socketTimeout = 1000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, socketTimeout);

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com");
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    httppost.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);;

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(parameters, "utf-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return ("ERROR_UnsupportedEncodingException");
    }
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String stream = null;

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        inputStream = entity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder a= new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            a.append(line + "\n");
        }

        stream = a.toString();

        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return ("ERROR_UnsupportedEncodingException");
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        return ("ERROR_ClientProtocolException");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return ("ERROR_IOException");
    }
```

Comment: show your error message from logcat

Comment: I get no error messages. This is the exception cause: java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Comment: We'll need to see additional surrounding code, particularly the code which initializes or assigns to `httppost`.